# throw new Error(string) not showing in F12

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling

I have a JS script that thrown an `Error`

```
$.when(verifyInitArgs(initArgs))
    .then(function argsAreValid() {
        initialiseForm();
    }, function argsInvalid(error) {
        throw new Error(error);
    });
```

the `error` variable is a `string`.  I can see this with `typeof` when a breakpoint is set:

```
>> typeof error
"string"
```

However, the thrown error is not showing in the console window in IE or Firefox.

If I enter `throw new Error("something");` directly in the browser console then it works as expected, it's displayed as an error in the console.

What's happening here?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? It may matter, as they've been trying to bring its Deferred objects into compliance with the Promises/A+ spec.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  `3.1.1`m however I can see that the promise is OK as I can hit a breakpoint on the `throw` line and see the value of `error`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that `then` (and `catch` and such) create a *new* promise that the code in your callback can affect the outcome of. In the Promises/A+ style of promises (JavaScript's native promises adhere to those semantics, and jQuery's been trying to bring Deferreds in line — and the v3.1.1 you're using is in line now I believe), when you throw in a promise `then` or `catch` callback, that exception is converted into a rejection of the promise created by the `then` or `catch` method.

So your `throw new Error(...)` is becoming a rejection of the promise returned by your call to `then`.

Browsers are updating their handling of *unhandled rejections* so that those appear in the console (support for this varies at present); it may be worth switching over to native promises.

Just for illustration, here's an example of a native promise throwing within a `then` callback:

```js
new Promise(function(resolve) {
  console.log("First promise resolving");
  resolve("all good");
}).then(function(resolution) {
  console.log("Got resolution " + resolution);
  console.log("Throwing error from second promise");
  throw new Error("ack!");
});
```

In recent Chrome, when you run that, if you open the real console (not just the in-snippet one) you'll see

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: ack!(…)
```

...to report the unhandled rejection.

In contrast, using jQuery v3.1.1, I don't see that error:

```js
var d = $.Deferred();
d.promise().then(function(resolution) {
  console.log("Got resolution " + resolution);
  console.log("Throwing error from second promise");
  throw new Error("ack!");
});
console.log("First promise resolving");
d.resolve("all good");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

...which is why it may be useful to switch over to native promises (if feasible in your project).

Comment: Might just be easier to use `console.error("Eek")`.  As long as it's not failing silently I'm happy.

Comment: @BanksySan: :-) Indeed.